# GreenRobot EventBus

Tags: java, android, mobile, greenrobot-eventbus

Does anyone have an example of using the `EventBusBuilder` for greenrobot's `Eventbus`?

I have an app that is using `EventBus.getDefault()` all over the place, but now I want to configure that bus to stop sending the no subscriber message. It is discussed here: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md

Since the code to configure an `EventBus`, seems to return an instance of the bus itself (from the doc above):

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBus.builder().logNoSubscriberMessages(false).sendNoSubscriberEvent(false).build();
```

I am just not sure where to put that instance! Do I have to make a singleton somewhere to include it, just like the `EventBus` library itself does? And then re-plumb all of my calls to `EventBus.getDefault()` to my own class?

Just a little confused. Help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Judd

Comment: Wrap it in your own class (singleton) would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't read the document carefully. [Here](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/) is what you want:

```
  EventBus.builder().logNoSubscriberMessages(false).
     sendNoSubscriberEvent(false).installDefaultEventBus();
```

Then `EventBus.getDefault()` should work with this config

Comment: So then I would just pick a place, maybe my main activity to make that single call - because it is the default bus anyway..?

Comment: You were right, I had an older version that did not have the .builder method.

Comment: I put it in the application class's onCreate

Comment: I have built a small test-app for eventBus3 : https://github.com/dineshvg/TutorialAppForEventBus , maybe that could come in useful for understanding.